# Deploying Laravel on Heroku "PDOException in Connector.php line 55" (sqlite)

Tags: php, database, sqlite, laravel, heroku

I tried to deploy my first Laravel project on Heroku. It's a small project, so I'm using SQLite as my database. After deploying the project using `git push heroku master`, and clicking on one of the links that retrieves data from the database to display an index, I am getting the following error:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver
in Connector.php line 55
at PDO->__construct('sqlite:/app/database/database.sqlite', null, null, array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in Connector.php line 55
at Connector->createConnection('sqlite:/app/database/database.sqlite', array('driver' => 'sqlite', 'database' => '/app/database/database.sqlite', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'sqlite'), array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in SQLiteConnector.php line 37
at SQLiteConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'sqlite', 'database' => '/app/database/database.sqlite', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'sqlite')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 61
at ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
at call_user_func(object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 875
at Connection->getPdo() in Connection.php line 743
at Connection->reconnectIfMissingConnection() in Connection.php line 628
at Connection->run('select * from "certificates" order by "updated_at" desc', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 342
at Connection->select('select * from "certificates" order by "updated_at" desc', array(), true) in Builder.php line 1562
at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1548
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 610
at Builder->getModels(array('*')) in Builder.php line 316
at Builder->get() in CertificatesController.php line 25
at CertificatesController->index()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CertificatesController), 'index'), array()) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('index', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(CertificatesController), object(Route), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(CertificatesController), object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'app\Http\Controllers\CertificatesController', 'index') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Anyone knows how I may be able to resolve this problem? Many thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3):

I've also encountered this on Heroku.

I added:

```
{
   "require": {
        "ext-pdo_sqlite": "*"
   }
}
```

Comment: I would like to add that it must be pushed and commited the composer.lock file once updated by composer install or update, and followingly the sqlite must be laravel migrated with `php artisan migrate` and the migrated database file must be also commited, as far as I am knowledgable, unless there is a way to migrate at Heroku

Answer (score -2):

Sqlite is setup as a shared extension on Heroku, but has to be enabled through `composer.json` i believe.

Try adding:

```
{
    "require": {
        "sqlite3": "*"
    }
}
```

To your `composer.json` file.