# My PHP site is working locally on apache, but when launching to Heroku I'm getting a PDO connection error

Tags: php, git, sqlite, heroku, composer-php

When I launch my site to Heroku after updating the composer, I get a 500 error. I looked in the Heroku logs and found this:

```
wd="71.175.25.164" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=279 protocol=https
2019-07-19T14:06:49.554554+00:00 app[web.1]: [19-Jul-2019 14:06:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /app/src/classes/connect.php:11
2019-07-19T14:06:49.554641+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2019-07-19T14:06:49.554867+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/src/classes/connect.php(11): PDO->__construct('sqlite:./src/db...')
2019-07-19T14:06:49.555326+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 /app/src/classes/user.php(46): Site\connect\Connection::connect('./src/db/users....')
2019-07-19T14:06:49.555504+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/index.php(72): Site\user\User->fetchAllUsers()
2019-07-19T14:06:49.555718+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 {main}
2019-07-19T14:06:49.555854+00:00 app[web.1]: thrown in /app/src/classes/connect.php on line 11
2019-07-19T14:06:49.556578+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.67.212.254 - - [19/Jul/2019:14:06:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
```

I've tried structuring my code different ways and adding a ./ to the beginning of the path. I have also tried running the composer update but to no avail.

I would like to see my code run on Heroku live so I can test it.

Comment: Your issue is `Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver` - The server you are attempting to run the code on is missing a driver, I'm assuming the `sqlite` driver or could be the PDO driver itself

Comment: How do I add the driver to the Heroku server? Im assuming adding something in my composer.json file? Not a clue honestly

Comment: @MattHippensteel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386926/deploying-laravel-on-heroku-pdoexception-in-connector-php-line-55-sqlite

Comment: This works @GrumpyCrouton .Problem solved. Thank you very much

Comment: @MattHippensteel, it probably _didn't_ work. [Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Anything you write to an SQLite database will be lost whenever your dyno restarts.

Comment: Your right, but this personal project is just a test before launching. GrumpyCrouton direction worked in that my site displayed on Heroku without error. @Chris thanks for pointing out that Heroku is not good for storing data persistently...